# Set Boolean extra in Manifest

Tags: android

Since i need to test my App with different starting parameters i am searching for a way to define these parameters in the Manifest for my launcher Activity such that i can retrieve them in the onCreate Method with 
`intent.getBooleanExtra()` method. i saw that it is possible to set `<meta-data>` to the launcher activity but the handling is not as beautiful as only accessing intent extras, so before sticking to this approach maybe someone has an idea how do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there is no means to specify extras in the manifest.